# What is the meaning of "mass voting continues to happen between two certain IP addresses"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> #### What is voting fraud?
>
> Voting fraud is the systematic voting against correct voting rationales. Fraud most often happens with a single user continually voting (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time. This is not considered normal behavior and the system will not allow it.
>
> If **mass voting continues to happen between two certain IP addresses** (voting each other up) or from a single user, or looks just plain suspicious in general, moderators and/or developers may investigate the matter and disciplinary action may be taken against the users involved with the fraud.

What is this meaning of highlighted sentence here?

Source: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: pls don't downvote **on purpose**. i already got warning message like [**here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF2h7.jpg).

Comment: Any online activity has a unique IP address. Tracking this address will give an information about from where the activity happened. For online voting, if 'mass voting' (too many votes) happens from the two different places, it is obvious that someone is doing it purposely. It'll be then considered as a spam. जैसे की तुम मेरे सब जवाब को उपवोटे करू और मे तुम्हारे सब जवाब को.. वो स्पामिंग कहलाती है!

Comment: @MaulikV please don't commenting in **hindi** which I don't know.

Comment: Dhanraj  - Please stop telling people what not to do, and learn to learn from feedback. People can downvote if they don’t think your question provides enough research or isn’t clear. The _Details, Please_ post provides many examples of how to ward off downvotes. This question doesn’t explain why you’re confused. (Do you not understand _mass voting_? Do you know what an IP address is?) or what research you have done to answer your question (Did you Google _mass voting_? Did you look up _mass_ in a dictionary? What did you find?) If you’re not going to divulge that information, expect downvotes.

Comment: I did not comment in Hindi, I **also** commented in Hindi! I rarely come across someone who is Indian and know nothing about Hindi. It was to help you with paraphrasing the sentence in another language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation directly follows the sentence. That explanation is there because the usage is indeed slightly unusual.

A bit longer explanation: votes are cast **by** users, but these votes come in via the web. Each user is logged in from a certain computer with a certain IP address. However, multiple users may be sharing the same IP address (e.g. in a single company).

Votes are cast **for** questions and answers. These are associated with users, which in turn are associated with IP addresses as noted above.

"voting between IP addresses" therefore means that users behind one IP address vote for questions and answers from users behind another IP address, and vice versa (in the other direction as well)